# How do I extract text from a file in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash, sed, scripting

I am tring to extract text from a multi-line file. For example
I need to extract all text from "Section 1.0" to "Section 3.0"

This can be on many lines.

I have code that works, but seems clumsy and slow. Is there a better way to do this?
sed?
reg expression?

```
flag="false"

for line in ${textFile}; 
do
   if [ "$line" == "Section 3.0" ]; then
      flag="false"
   fi
   if [ "$flag" == "true" ]; then
      temp_var+=$line
   fi
   if [ "$line" == "Section 1.0" ]; then
      flag="true"
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Using sed you can do:

```
sed -n '/Section 1\.0/,/Section 3\.0/p' file
```

**EDIT:** To ignore start and end patterns use:

```
sed -n '/Section 1\.0/,/Section 3\.0/{/Section [13]\.0/!p;}' file
```

**awk solution:**

```
awk '/Section 1\.0/{flag=0} flag{print} /Section 3\.0/{flag=1}' file
```

Comment: Yes section 1 comes before section 3. The code is the way it is so the actual section title does not get written.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/Section 1\.0/,/Section 3\.0/p' file
```

will print from `file` all lines between a line matching the first regex anywhere in it through the next line matching the second expression. If there are multiple such matches, they will be printed in flip-flop fashion (look for pattern 1, print through pattern 2, look for pattern 1...)

If you want only the first such section, you can quit when you find the end condition:

```
sed -n '/Section 3\.0/q;/Section 1\.0/,$p' file
```

This will exclude the line matching the end condition (guessing that's what you actually want). For simplicity, this assumes you have no Section 3.0 before Section 1.0. (Some `sed` dialects might require slighly different syntax; the semicolon may have to be changed to a newline, or the script split into two separate `-e` arguments.)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can also be used:

```
awk '/Section 3\.0/{f=0} f; /Section 1\.0/{f=1}' file
```